# Im having a problem with finding the palindrome of a upper case and lower case version of a word

Tags: java

So, I'm meant to get two version of a word given by user input, a version with just the lower case letters and then a version with just the upper case letters. Im then meant to find out if both of the words are palindromes. For example if the word was 'HEllO', the words HEO and ll would be created and then the output "HEO is not a palindrome, ll is a palindrome" would be printed. Im pretty sure my code makes sense but it won't say if either version of the original word is a palindrome. The following is the code.

````
public class comp1 
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        
        String lower = lowerCaseLetters(input);
        String upper = upperCaseLetters(input);
        
        palindromeUpper(upper);
        palindromeLower(lower);
    }
    
    public static String lowerCaseLetters(String input)
    {
        char[] ar = new char[input.length()];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            if(Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(i))) 
            {
                ar[i] = input.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        
        String lowercase = new String(ar);
        return lowercase;
    }
    
    public static String upperCaseLetters(String input)
    {
        char[] ar = new char[input.length()];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) 
            {
                ar[i] = input.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        
        String uppercase = new String(ar);
        return uppercase;
    }
    
    public static void palindromeUpper(String sent)
    {
        String reverse = "";
        
        for(int i = sent.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverse += sent.charAt(i);
        }
        
        if(sent.equals(reverse))
        {
            System.out.println("Upper case " + sent + " is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Upper case " + sent + " is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
    
    public static void palindromeLower(String sent)
    {
        String reverse = "";
        
        for(int i = sent.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverse += sent.charAt(i);
        }
        
        if(sent.equals(reverse))
        {
            System.out.println("Lower case " + sent + " is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Lower case " + sent + " is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

arrays don't skip 'empty' values. In fact, there's no such thing as an empty slot; `char[] ar = new char[input.length()];` gives you a char array with *length* slots, and each slot is filled with an actual character: The NUL character.

You then copy over all lowercase letters to their appropriate position, which means all non-lowercase letters still have the NUL character. You then turn this back into a string, which will be a string with lots of NUL characters, and those NUL characters will then prevent the rest of your code from working properly; `ll` is a palindrome, sure. but `\0\0ll\0` is not.

You can't resize arrays, you need to create them at the right size. Thus, you have two options:

1. loop through the string twice. First time, you just count lowercase letters, that is all you do. Second time, you copy over the lowercase letters, and not to position `i`, but to a counter you maintain (the first l occurs at `i=2`, but needs to go into `ar[0]`. The second l occurs at `i=3`, and needs to go into `ar[1]`).
2. Don't use a char array; use a `StringBuilder` instead, which grows on demand. just `.append` any lowercase letters.

2 is probably easier, but involves the use of another class (`java.lang.StringBuilder`).

Note then that your `palindromeLower` and `palindromeUpper` methods are identical, other than the messaging.